# sorting a list of lists from shortest to longest

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have to order a list of lists of numbers from shortest to longest. At equality of lenght, in ascending order.

```
input=[[19, -3, 2, -10, -20], [22, 2, -10, -20], [19, -3, 12, -20], [19, -3, 2, 10], [20, -10, -20], [22, 12, -20], [22, 2, 10], [30, -20], [20, 10], [50], [10], [10, -20], [22, 32], [30], [19, -3, 32]]
```

expected output:

```
[(10,), (30,), (50,), 
    (10, -20), (20, 10), (22, 32), (30, -20), 
    (19, -3, 32), (20, -10, -20), (22, 2, 10), (22, 12, -20), 
    (19, -3, 2, 10), (19, -3, 12, -20), (22, 2, -10, -20), 
    (19, -3, 2, -10, -20)]
```

Comment: Your questions says: `from longest to shortest` your example is sorted from shortest to longest. Which are you after?

Comment: Did you try something? I am guessing you are familiar with the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function. If not, have a read in that link, particularly the part on the `key` argument ... ;)

Comment: i'm sorry i made a mistake writing the question. follow the example.. from shortest to longest

Comment: You could just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57234053/edit) your question to fix that swo it is clear

Comment: @simone13, do you really need to get a list of **tuples** as a result?

Comment: you forgot to change the sorting order in the title of your question

Answer (score 2):

The answer your looking for is

```
sorted(input, key=lambda l: (len(l), l))
```

Comment: And then you need to convert your result to tuples

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to sort by *length* and a tuple itself to get the expected result:

```
input_lst = [[19, -3, 2, -10, -20], [22, 2, -10, -20], [19, -3, 12, -20], [19, -3, 2, 10], [20, -10, -20], [22, 12, -20], [22, 2, 10], [30, -20], [20, 10], [50], [10], [10, -20], [22, 32], [30], [19, -3, 32]]
res = sorted(input_lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[[10], [30], [50], [10, -20], [20, 10], [22, 32], [30, -20], [19, -3, 32], [20, -10, -20], [22, 2, 10], [22, 12, -20], [19, -3, 2, 10], [19, -3, 12, -20], [22, 2, -10, -20], [19, -3, 2, -10, -20]]
```

If you actually need to get a result as a list of tuples change the crucial line to the following:

```
res = sorted(map(tuple, input_lst), key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

Comment: should be `(22, 2, 10), (22, 12, -20)`. I am guessing it is not according to just the first element, but say "lexographical" order if the length is the same, which is actually the default of comparing iterables

Answer (score 0):

Just sort it with a custom key which would sort based on sublist length and use the values of the list for lists of same length

```
>>> input.sort(key=lambda l: (len(l), l))
>>> print (*input, sep='\n')
[10]
[30]
[50]
[10, -20]
[20, 10]
[22, 32]
[30, -20]
[19, -3, 32]
[20, -10, -20]
[22, 2, 10]
[22, 12, -20]
[19, -3, 2, 10]
[19, -3, 12, -20]
[22, 2, -10, -20]
[19, -3, 2, -10, -20]
```